# Trouble launching display.launch.py file

Tags: ubuntu, ros-humble, ros2-launch

I'm using ROS 2 ubuntu 22.04 Humble.

i had made a model in fusion 360 and would like to make a gazebo simulation from it. i have tried the extension by https://github.com/dheena2k2/fusion2urdf-ros2. i built the package, sourced it and tried to run it using ros2 launch rover_description display.launch.py. it gives me an error saying

[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]: substitution args not supported: No module named 'roslaunch'.

These are the steps i did:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd dev_ws/
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/dev_ws$ colcon build
Starting >>> my_bot  
Starting >>> my_package
Starting >>> rover_description                                       
Finished <<< my_package [1.38s]                                          
Finished <<< my_bot [1.54s]                                  
Finished <<< rover_description [2.24s]          

Summary: 3 packages finished [3.54s]
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/dev_ws$ source install/setup.bash
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/dev_ws$ ros2 launch rover_description display.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/2023-12-17-08-11-52-523673-ubuntu-4146
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]: substitution args not supported:  No module named 'roslaunch'
```

My `display.launch.py` file looks like this

````py
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch import LaunchDescription
import launch_ros.descriptions
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument,ExecuteProcess
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.conditions import IfCondition, UnlessCondition
import xacro
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


def generate_launch_description():
    share_dir = get_package_share_directory('rover_description')

    xacro_file = os.path.join(share_dir, 'urdf', 'rover.xacro')
    robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(xacro_file)
    robot_urdf = robot_description_config.toxml()

    rviz_config_file = os.path.join(share_dir, 'config', 'display.rviz')

    gui_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        name='gui',
        default_value='True'
    )

    show_gui = LaunchConfiguration('gui')

    robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        name='robot_state_publisher',
        parameters=[
            {'robot_description': robot_urdf}
        ]
    )

    joint_state_publisher_node = Node(
        condition=UnlessCondition(show_gui),
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        name='joint_state_publisher'
    )

    joint_state_publisher_gui_node = Node(
        condition=IfCondition(show_gui),
        package='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        executable='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        name='joint_state_publisher_gui'
    )

    rviz_node = Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        arguments=['-d', rviz_config_file],
        output='screen'
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        gui_arg,
        robot_state_publisher_node,
        joint_state_publisher_node,
        joint_state_publisher_gui_node,
        rviz_node
    ])
```
````

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didnt properly source my workspace it was supposed to be like

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/dev_ws$ source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/dev_ws$ source install/setup.bash
```

rookie mistake!