# fusion 360 to gazebo in ROS2

Tags: gazebo, ros2, rviz, roslaunch, ros-humble

i am using ubuntu 22.04 humble.

i had made a model in fusion 360 and would like to make a gazebo simulation from it. i have tried the extension by https://github.com/dheena2k2/fusion2urdf-ros2. i built the package, sourced it and tried to run it using ros2 launch rover_description display.launch.py. it gives me an error saying

> [ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for
> traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]:
> substitution args not supported:  No module named 'roslaunch'.

i would appreciate if you could suggest any better repositories for fusion to urdf convertion in ROS2

Comment: The error seems to come from the lack of the right packages installation for Humble (particularly roslaucnh). Please follow the ROS base installation https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your [previous question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/107096/9176), especially seeing as the solution is the same for both.

Answer (score 1):

solved it!. I didnt properly source my workspace it was supposed to be like

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/dev_ws$ source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/dev_ws$ source install/setup.bash
```

rookie mistake :)

Comment: Thanks for the follow up here to help others who might run into your problem. I've tweaked your formatting for better readability.